# Css target toggle - initial set to visible

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html/css toggle set up

```css
#toggle1 {
  display: none;
}

#toggle1:target {
  display: block;
}

#toggle2 {
  display: none;
}

#toggle2:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#toggle1">Show1</a><br />
<a href="#toggle2">Show2</a>
<p id="toggle1">1</p>
<p id="toggle2">2</p>
```

This works as desired by showing and hiding. However I want the initial paragraph to be visible upon page load. If I remove the `#toggle1 {display: none;}` it does not work properly.

Any assistance would be most helpful and appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a bit of a hack, but if you reverse the order of the hidden elements, add `display:block` to the "default" one and then add `display:none` to `:target ~ #toggle1` it should simulate a default selected item:

```css
#toggle1, #toggle1:target, #toggle2:target {
  display: block;
}
:target ~ #toggle1, #toggle2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#toggle1">Show1</a><br />
<a href="#toggle2">Show2</a>
<p id="toggle2">2</p>
<p id="toggle1">1</p>
```

Comment: Clever solution +1

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JosephMarikle - quick follow up, what if I had n number of these and not just two, say I needed 5 would we need to do anything differently?

Comment: @JosephMarikle - never mind, answered myself. Just keep the first one last in the ordering and good to go.